# Mesh shrink problem

Tags: rigging

I checked weight paints and other things but I'm noob in Blender.

[image: shrink pic]

Comment: Hello, check the normals of your mesh, also check if the weight paint is correct in Weight Paint mode, if it doesnt't work please share your file